# Laravel `model->update($data)` changes pm times to am

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

My times appear to be updating correctly but when I look for the field in my database (mysql) I see the times are changed to ***AM***. This happens with `->update` but not `::create`

Here is my
**$data = Input::all()** before the `->update` call

```
array(14) { ["_method"]=> string(5) "PATCH" 
            ["_token"]=> string(40) "A3OknqVoHtva73nn5HZTBYyFd8v42WOUNlc3ED5G" 
            ["start_time"]=> string(6) "4:30pm" 
            ["end_time"]=> string(6) "5:30pm" 
           }
```

Here is my controller code.

**controller**

```
public function update($id)
{
    $scheduled_program = ScheduledProgram::findOrFail($id);

    $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), ScheduledProgram::$rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
      return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput()->with('id', $id);
    }

    if($validator->passes()) {
        $scheduled_program->update($data);
        $scheduled_program->save();
        dd($scheduled_program);
    }
}
```

The `dd($scheduled_program)` shows

`["start_time"]=> string(6) "4:30pm" 
 ["end_time"]=> string(6) "5:30pm"`

but in my database, I see AM values `04:30:00   05:30:00` and when I open a page that displays the values, they are AM values. It appears that the model is updating but it gets converted to AM values in the database.

Comment: add "start_time" and "end_time" to $dates array on the model. Then you have to update $data array as following $dates['start_date']=Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat("g:ia", $dates['start_date']); and same for end_date

Comment: "start_time" and "end_time" are already part of the model and fields in my database table, do I need to make them an array inside "$dates"? 

Should I put this in the controller or is there a better place like the validator or rules? 
Thanks!

Comment: You have to tell model that those needs to treat as dates(as carbon instances). so you need to add those into protected variable $dates in model(as in here https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#soft-deleting). when you retrieving those you will get Carbon objects instead of string variables

Comment: $dates didn't work with my `time` formatted str types :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You workaround this by using Eloquent Accessors and Mutators to automatically set or get the right format.

I said automatically because you don't need to call accessors or mutators directly but you simple do something like this:

```
 User::find(1)->start_time;
```

In the background the accessor method will do its work automatically.

Checkout Laravel documentation Eloquent section for detail

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators

You need to add this to your model.

```
public function setStartTimeAttribute($value) { 
     $this->attributes['start_time'] = date("H:i:s", strtotime($value)); 
 }


 public function getStartTimeAttribute($value) { 
    return date("g:i a", strtotime($value)); 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. This fixed my problem. I have this time field in many different models. Do I need to put this code into each model or is there a way to do it once?

Comment: Have to put it in each model that's the way to use accessors and mutators